# using glutBitmapCharacter() to draw text closing opengl program

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glfw, opengl-compat

When I try draw text using a function called `drawText()` the function runs smoothly but when it reaches `glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, (int)text[i]);` the program unexpectedly closes. I have tested that it is this specific part of the function causing this as if I where to remove it and replace it with `printf("Hello World!\n");` the program doesn't crash.

Main function:

```
int main(void) {
    GLFWwindow* window;
    int width = 840, height = 640;
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        printf("failed to init glfw");
        return -1;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "ElectroCraft", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (!window) {
        printf("failed to start window");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, 0, 1000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearColor(53.0f / 255.0f, 81.0f / 255.0f, 92.0f / 255.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f(0, height-80);
        glVertex2f(width, height - 80);
        glEnd();

        string text;
        text = "Hello World!";
        //glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, int(text[1]));
        drawText(text.data(), text.size(), 50, 100);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 1;
}
```

drawText function:

```
void drawText(const char* text, int length, int x, int y) {
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    double* matrix = new double[16];
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, matrix);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 800, 0, 600, -5, 5);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRasterPos2i(x, y);
    for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, (int)text[i]);
        printf("Hello world!\n");
    }
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrixd(matrix);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

I am not exactly sure if it's my code not being the best or if there's a bug in freeglut library. Just to be clear I'm using freeglut.

Comment: You can't use `glutBitmapCharacter` without calling `glutInit()`.

Comment: "Just to be clear I'm using freeglut."...then why are you using GLFW functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use any function of the [*GLUT*](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) library, then *GLUT* has to be initialized  by [`glutInit`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node10.html). e.g.:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    // [...]
}
```

Comment: what is &argc, argv whats do I put for those arguments

Comment: This are the command line arguments to the application. See [Main function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function). You can copy/paste the code of the answer.