# what is glut drawText doing

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I wish ppl can help explain the code below.

The code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58642343/using-glutbitmapcharacter-to-draw-text-closing-opengl-program), and it works.

The main questions can include the uses of the following functions in order to draw the text.

- `glGetDoublev`
- `glPushMatrix`
- `glPopMatrix`
- `glLoadMatrixd(matrix)`

Why we use them ?

The full code is presented again as below :

```
void drawText(const char* text, int length, int x, int y) {

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    double* matrix = new double[16];
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, matrix);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrtho(0, 800, 0, 600, -5, 5);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    glRasterPos2i(x, y);
    for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, (int)text[i]);
        printf("Hello world!\n");
    }

    glPopMatrix();

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrixd(matrix);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Comment: Has the question been answered?

Answer (score 0):

The position of the bitmap text is transformed by the current model view and projection matrix, because the coordinates of [`glRasterPos2i`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRasterPos.xml) are transformed by the current model view and projection matrices. If you do not want to transform the coordinates, or if you want to use a different transformation such as the orthographic projection in the example, you must load the identity matrices or load a different transformation matrix.
Alternatively you can use [`glWindowPos`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glWindowPos.xml). The coordinates of `glWindowPos` are not transformed:

```cpp
 void drawText(const char* text, int length, int x, int y) {

    glWindowPos2f((float)x / 400.0f - 1.0f, (float)y / 300.0f - 1.0f);
    for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, (int)text[i]);
        printf("Hello world!\n");
    }
}
```